# Ограничить область просмотра Yandex map JavaScript API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Ограничить область просмотра на карте yandex map

Пример: Google maps

```
    restriction: { latLngBounds: { north: 83.8, south: -83.8, west: -180, east: 180 } },
```

Answer (score 1):

У карты есть опция [`restrictMapArea`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#Map__param-options.restrictMapArea).